# Unable to scrape data from a website: Python BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this [Platform](http://data.corkcity.ie/dataset/f4ff0fe7-844d-485a-b57e-a6ac2f06dfae/resource/6cc1028e-7388-4bc5-95b7-667a59aa76dc/view/c040ab65-4c73-4348-8e19-261529bbf521) using BS4 with python. I have tried many approaches but i am not able to retrieve any information. Looks like its a direct response from API or something. Can somebody help me here in right direction ?

Data to be scraped:

[image: Data]

Thank you,

Comment: For this kind of dynamic content, the data is likely not loaded in the page itself, it is generated dynamically. If the site provides API access, you could try to use that; if not, I would try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) for the scraping as it can handle asynchronous loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what requests are being made on the page using the chrome inspector. The page is making a request to http://data.corkcity.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search

Here's a snippet using requests that pulls the data and outputs it as json:

```
import requests 
import json
resp = requests.post(
    "http://data.corkcity.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search",
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data=json.dumps(
        {
            "resource_id": "6cc1028e-7388-4bc5-95b7-667a59aa76dc",
            "filters": {},
            "limit": 10,
            "offset": 0,
        }
    ),
)
resp.json()
```

Comment: so what you meant is the above snippet will let me pull the same data which is being published ? I have tried to use snippet but looks like no response

Comment: Solved , Thank you